# Python begginer - Can someone tell me why this loop don't finish?

Tags: python

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
  # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
  while n % 2 == 0:
    n = n / 2
  # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
  if n == 1:
    return True
  if n != 0:
    return False

print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False
```

This is a excercice from Coursera's Python course. I don't know why it don't finish when n=0.

Comment: When you pass `n = 0` then `n = n / 2` will continue to re-assign `0` to `n`, and therefore the condition for your `while` loop is always `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while n % 2 == 0:` will turns out to be a `infinate loop`.

This happening because

First number input is `0`

`while n % 2 == 0:`  ---> `0 ==0`  --> True

```
While True:
    #This is infinate loop.
```

### Code correction

To avoid this check if n is zero or not before while.

```
def is_power_of_two(n):

  if n ==0:
      return False
  # Check if the number can be divided by two without a remainder
  while n % 2 == 0:
    n = n / 2
  # If after dividing by two the number is 1, it's a power of two
  if n == 1:
    return True
  if n != 0:
    return False



print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False
```

Gives #

```
False
True
True
False
```

Comment: You changed the `while` into `if`.  It should still be `while`.

Comment: @RufusVS not seen that just updated